# MySQL database sync options

Tags: mysql, replication, data-synchronization

What are some of the good options to sync two or more MySQL databases of the same schema, situated at different locations; reliably?

We have four database in four different locations.

we tried using the generic master master replication but the link breaks again and again leading to inconsistencies.

Comment: Not a MySQL expert, but you'll want to include more info here for others: MySQL Version, where are the different locations, do you need master-master functionality or is read-only secondary fine, what type of load does your system have, hosted in the cloud or internally, etc. - these are all important factors

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that *can* go wrong in Master-Master.  Use Master-Master, but do not write to both masters.  Pick one for all writes; leave the other one for failover.